# I have 2 .thumbdata files

Tags: internal-storage

I have 2 .thumbdata files on my tab for some reason. My tab is the lenovo M10 16GB model
I have some space issues so I was trying to delete some unnecessary files and I came accross DCIM I researched and learner that .thumbdata was a deletable file. My question is,is it normal to have 2 .thumbdata file and if I delete one what will be the consequences?